# How to leave a GitLab project not owned by me?

Tags: gitlab

If I had contributed in  a project, for which I am not an owner or administrator, how can I get myself out of that project? I do not find the leave button as documented  in issue 744.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/744

The project owner has stopped responding to me and I badly want myself out of it. Please help.

Comment: where is your effort?

Comment: Seems like a bug. I've commented about it in the (closed) PR.

Comment: Look at this also https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4221.

Answer (score 15):

Updated answer for 2020:
Leaving a group automatically removes you from all projects added by that group.

At the top menu chose Groups\Your Groups. Select the group you want to leave and press leave.

Comment: You can leave a group that way, but how do you leave a project that's not in a group?

Comment: I have to leave each project one by one. Following your instruction I really can't find a "leave" options for a group.

Comment: @Mark there's a curved arrow icon on each row; hovering over it, you should see the title text "leave group". This is, so far, the only method I've found that actually works for leaving a group not owned by the user in the current version of GitLab.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum, you're right. I didn't realize the curved arrow icon would mean "leave group"!. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Follow these steps:

- On projects page select the project
- On top right corner select settings button
- Then select members
- Finally you'll see **LEAVE** button here

Comment: thanks, this works. settings is now on the left sidebar.

Comment: Indeed, settings button is moved to the left side, but this (for some kind of reason) is not working always. I have 2 projects not owned by me, for one I have a leave button which I can press, for other I dont, which is really weird!?

Answer (score 7):

Follow These steps

1. Go to the main project url, not the sub urls
   E.g If the project name is hng-interns -- Go to https://gitlab.com/hng-interns instead of https://gitlab.com/hng-interns/factory
2. Click on the Leave group button
3. Click okay in the alert box that shows up.

That's all!

Comment: hi, i was added to a group but i don't see the leave button in the main page, how can i leave ?

Answer (score 3):

In new gitlab version, you can leave a project not owned by you, by following these steps:

1- Go to the project page

2- Click on Project Information at the top left corner

3- Click on members

4- Find your name among members and click on red leave button

Answer (score 0):

Click **Menu** on the top left, **Groups**, **Your groups**.

Click on **Your groups** on the next page that loads.

Select Group

You will see picture similar two the second screenshot below. Instead of **Withdraw Access Request** you'll see **Leave Group**

[image]

[image]