# How do I leave a GitLab Project/Group in 2020

Tags: gitlab, missing-features

I've seen answers like this one: [How to leave a GitLab project not owned by me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500158/how-to-leave-a-gitlab-project-not-owned-by-me)

However its outdated since the UI has changed since then. I've looked under every Group/Project tab and its not there. I've also followed this link that GitLab itself gave me https://gitlab.com/groups/[GROUP_NAME]/-/group_members/leave and its a 404. I need to leave these groups/projects since they require 2FA and I recently disabled it (No, I don't want to re-enable it).

Anyone know how I can actually leave these things in 2020?

EDIT:

These repos are private (And I think the group is too). I see the option next to the Project ID on the main page on a public repo, but its missing for these private repos I want to remove...weird.

EDIT 2:

I got in contact with the Projects/Group owner and asked him to kick me and that worked. Still if anyone knows why I couldn't leave on my own it would be helpful for others who might have this problem in the future.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on "Groups" in the head menu bar
2. Choose "Your Groups"
3. Click on "Members" in the left sidebar
4. Click on "Leave" button next to your name

Comment: Thanks for the response. If this happens again I'll try this method

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the URL these days is `https://gitlab.com/{group_name}?leave=1`.

But when I tried it I was greeted by the following error message, which by itself is very self-explanatory. This would also explain why you cannot find the "Leave" button anywhere on the screen.

```
You do not have permission to leave this group.
```

I'd say you did the right thing - reaching out to the group owner.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving a group automatically removes you from all projects added by that group.
At the top menu chose Groups\Your Groups. Select the group you want to leave and press leave.